# How to turn a flattened structures with repetitions into a nested structure?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I can't find a recursive function for the following problem.
Assume the following paths, with their repetition which should turn into a nested structure like below. Is there a recursive solution? If not, any ideas for a short iterative solution?

| Path | Repetition |
| --- | --- |
| /a | 1 |
| /a/b | 1 |
| /a/c | 2 |
| /a/d | 2 |
| /a/d/e | 2 |
| /a/f | 1 |
| /a/g | 1 |

Output should be like this for a List<Pair<Path,Integer>> in **that specific order**:

/a 
/a/b 
**/a/c** 
**/a/c** 
/a/d 
**/a/d/e** 
**/a/d/e** 
/a/d 
**/a/d/e** 
**/a/d/e** 
/a/f 
/a/g

Comment: Unclear: You want the "output" to be nested, but the "output" in your example is just printed text? Should the output be a nested list, like `[[a], [ab], [ac, ac], [ad], ...]`?

Comment: What would you expect the output to be if I added in `{"/a/b/c/d/e/f/g", 1}` to the table after  `"/a/d/e"`?  And are the `Path` and `repetition` entries guaranteed to occur only once for each `Path` in the table?

Comment: Yes, each path can be listed only once. /a/b/c/d/e/f/g would not be possible, since the Paths build upon each other. So it would need to to be /a, /a/b, /a/b/c, /a/b/c/d, ... consecutive in the table

Comment: @Cobby  Thanks.  That's important info to know.  Especially about the paths being built upon each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Path, Integer> input = new LinkedHashMap();
        input.put(Path.of("/a"), 1);
        input.put(Path.of("/a/b"), 1);
        input.put(Path.of("/a/c"), 2);
        input.put(Path.of("/a/d"), 2);
        input.put(Path.of("/a/d/e"), 2);
        input.put(Path.of("/a/f"), 1);
        input.put(Path.of("/a/g"), 1);
        printElement(Path.of("/a"), input);
    }

    static void printElement(Path s, Map<Path, Integer> m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.get(s); i++) {
            System.out.println(s);
            m.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(map -> map.getKey().getParent().equals(s))
                    .forEach(map -> printElement(map.getKey(), m));
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following:

```
/a
/a/b
/a/c
/a/c
/a/d
/a/d/e
/a/d/e
/a/d
/a/d/e
/a/d/e
/a/f
/a/g
```

Comment: How would the iterative version look like?

Comment: Also, is this a simple preorder depth-first recursion?

Comment: For the iterative version, we need to add a data structure (stack) to store the given Path and iterate multiple times over it, adding and removing Path until the stack is empty. This solution is less intuitive.
Yes, it is a preorder depth-first recursion

Answer (score 0):

If using java 8 or above,you could deploy `stream` api

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<Path,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Path> result = list.stream()
                  .flatMap(ExpandingFlattenedList::getPathStream)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Stream<Path> getPathStream(Pair<Path, Integer> pair) {
        Supplier<Path> supplier=()-> pair.getKey();
        return Stream.generate(supplier)
                .limit(pair.getValue());
    }
```